# The 'ObjectContent' type failed to serialize

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API with a local DB where I created the controller using my database models. At all classes models where I have foreign keys I keep getting this error.

> Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Product_9B61A36C2BD0C13AA03EB8B09F2678CB0976D5E84057A4447E1FAF98EBDB7865' with data contract name 'Product_9B61A36C2BD0C13AA03EB8B09F2678CB0976D5E84057A4447E1FAF98EBDB7865:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.

I tried using **[DataContract]** , **[KnownType..]** and **[DataMember]** but it keeps getting this error. Do you know what I have to do?

This is one of my classes code:

```
    namespace WholesaleRetailProject
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [KnownType(typeof(Category))]
    [KnownType(typeof(ProductExport))]
    [DataContract]
    public partial class Product
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Product()
        {
            this.ProductExport = new HashSet<ProductExport>();
        }

        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public int ProductCode { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public double ProductSellPrice { get; set; }
        public int ProductCategoryID { get; set; }
        public int ProductStock { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<ProductExport> ProductExport { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Is `ProductExport` a class you have defined?

Comment: Also, there's a helpful shortcut so you don't have to make a constructor: `public virtual ICollection<ProductExport> ProductExport { get; set; } = new HashSet<ProductExport>();`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad practice to use full domain models to pass data via controllers. You can create custom Dto and then use automapper, to bind data from domain model to dto. In dto you can remove 'partial' and 'virtual' keywords, and exclude nesessary object properties.